# Is there a more compact/better way to ZIP multiple lists using LINQ in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

I am performing a specific operation that I believe is a multi-zip operation. I start with a with a JObject/JToken:

```
{
  "value1": "one,two,three",
  "value2": "four,five,six",
  "value3": "seven,eight,nine"
}
```

And I have specific keys/values that I want to extract & split strings and then combine. For example the list of keys I might be given is:

```
List<string> keys = new List<string> { "value1", "value2" };
```

At the end I want to return a JToken/JArray that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "value1": "one",
    "value2": "four"
  },
  {
    "value1": "two",
    "value2": "five"
  },
  {
    "value1": "three",
    "value2": "six"
  }
]
```

Note that only the specified keys' values are split and combined. I have coded a way to do this below, but I believe it is very bulky and could be made more compact. Any suggestions to make it more compact without losing efficiency (or even improving) will be appreciated.

```
        JToken token = JToken.Parse(response);
        Console.WriteLine(token);

        List<string> keys = new List<string> { "value1", "value2" };

        List<List<string>> values = keys.Select(key => token[key].Value<string>().Split(',').ToList()).ToList();
        List<Dictionary<string, string>> final = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
        for(int i = 0; i < values[0].Count; i++) {
            Dictionary<string, string> splitValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            for (int t = 0; t < keys.Count; t++) {
                splitValues[keys[t]] = values[t][i];
            }
            final.Add(splitValues);
        }

        JToken parsedResponse = JToken.FromObject(final);
        Console.WriteLine(parsedResponse);
```

Comment: Also you can assume perfect conditions (i.e the number of strings for each key is the same)

Comment: If you have working code then this seems like it might make more sense on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up only with following:

```
var json = @"{
    'value1': 'one,two,three',
  'value2': 'four,five,six',
  'value3': 'seven,eight,nine'
}";
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,string>>(json);
var keys = new List<string> { "value1", "value2" };
var result = dict
    .Where(kvp => keys.Contains(kvp.Key))
    .Select(kvp => (key: kvp.Key, values: kvp.Value.Split(",")))
    .Aggregate(
        (List<Dictionary<string, string>>) null, 
        (acc, curr) => 
        {
            if(acc == null)
            {
                return curr.values
                    .Select(value => new Dictionary<string, string> { { curr.key, value }})
                    .ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < curr.values.Length; i++)
                {
                    acc[i][curr.key] = curr.values[i];
                }
                return acc;
            }
        });
```

It is up to you to decide if it is cleaner way, but I think that at least deserilizing to `Dictionary<string, string>` and filtering with LINQ (stuff before aggregate) can make your code cleaner. As for performance you will need to benchmark it on your real data, for me in some cases parsing to `Dictionary` proved to be a better option than working `JObject`/`JToken`.